# A weird moment.js thing

Tags: javascript, momentjs

So I had this bit of code in an if statement as follows

```
if (!inTime || !moment(inTime).format('m') % 15 === 0) {
doSomething();
}
```

The inTime getting passed in was 2018-10-11T20:00:25Z. for some reason that condition was met and the code in the if block was being called. After some tooling around I found two fixes for the issue as follows

```
if (!inTime || !(moment(inTime).format('m') % 15 === 0)) {
doSomething();
}
```

*note the parens after the bang and after the 0
or I could do this

```
if (!inTime || !moment(inTime).minute() % 15 === 0) {
doSomething();
}
```

I was curious to know if anyone knows why this happens?

Comment: you have 0 minutes. `0 % 15` is `0`

Comment: right but the bang should make the condition get run if it's not 0

Comment: @AustenElswick the `!` is applied just to the Moment `.format()` call result, not the `===` comparison.

Answer (score 1):

The expression

```
!moment(inTime).format('m') % 15 === 0
```

is interpreted as if it were written

```
((!moment(inTime).format('m')) % 15) === 0
```

So its evaluation proceeds as

1. `moment(inTime).format('m')` gives the string "0"
2. `!moment(inTime).format('m')` gives boolean `false`, because "0" is truthy
3. `((!moment(inTime).format('m')) % 15)` gives the number 0, after `false` is converted to a number (`0`) and the modulus is computed
4. `((!moment(inTime).format('m')) % 15) === 0` gives `true`

tl;dr the `!` binds very tightly.

Since you've got an ISO date string, it might be simpler to just use the native Date API:

```
if (!inTime || new Date(inTime).getMinutes() % 15 !== 0)
```